# appcfg.py upload_data is failing with expected <directory> even though I've got it

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having trouble getting the bulk uploader to work.  I have been
following the tutorial here:http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/
python/tools/uploadingdata.html.

When I enter the following command (from Windows, using PowerShell)

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=src/friend_loader.py --filename=frienddata.csv --kind=Friend ./src/
```

I get the following error:

> Usage: appcfg.py [options] upload_data
>
> appcfg.py: error: Expected 
>   argument.

This seems to happen no matter how I change the order of the
arguments, where the files are or any other combination that I have
tried.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any more information when you add "--noisy" ? Are you logged in before you run above line ?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that flag.  The odd thing is that it seems to not make any difference on the WinXP machine that I was working on.  To make it odder, the flag, and the upload worked just fine on my Windows 7 lappy.   This helped me track down the issue with the install on my WinXP machine.

Answer (score 0):

the last parameter ./src/  could you explain what are you using it for?
the tools is expecting a parameter of: the app_Id of your app running on the google app engine or the root path of your applicacion generally is something like.

```
/appcfg.py --config_file=person_loader.py --kind=person --filename=persons.csv --url=http://employee.appspot.com/remote_api   download_data 2010employee010
```

where 2010employee010 is the app_ID or you can make it at this other way:

```
/appcfg.py --config_file=person_loader.py --kind=person --filename=persons.csv --url=http://employee.appspot.com/remote_api   download_data employee/
```

where employee/ is the root path where the app is running or it was started.